# Ionic 3: PDFmake not working on real devices

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my application, there is a screen for generating PDFs. On the web browser, the PDF is getting downloaded, the content is displayed but on mobile it is getting downloaded and saved in PDF format and the content is not getting written to the PDF.

Plugin used: `cordova pdfMake`

Here is the code for reference

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
import {  File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import {  FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  letterObj = {
    to: '',
    from: '',
    text: ''
  }
  public signatureImage : any;
  pdfObj = null;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private plt: Platform, 
    private file: File, private fileOpener: FileOpener,public navParams:NavParams ) {
    this.signatureImage = navParams.get('signatureImage');
  }
  createPdf() {
    var docDefinition = {
      content: [
        { text: 'REMINDER', style: 'header' },
        { text: new Date().toTimeString(), alignment: 'right' },

        { text: 'From', style: 'subheader' },
        { text: this.letterObj.from },

        { text: 'To', style: 'subheader' },
        this.letterObj.to,
        { text: this.letterObj.text, style: 'story', margin: [0, 20, 0, 20] },
        {
          image: this.signatureImage , style: 'foo',
          fit: [100, 100] ,alignment:'right'
          },
        // {
        //   ul: [
        //     'Bacon',
        //     'Rips',
        //     'BBQ',
        //   ]
        // }
      ],
      styles: {
        header: {
          fontSize: 18,
          bold: true,
        },
        subheader: {
          fontSize: 14,
          bold: true,
          margin: [0, 15, 0, 0]
        },
        story: {
          italic: true,
          alignment: 'center',
          width: '50%',
        },
        foo:{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: "100%",
          right: '100%',
        }
      }
    }
    this.pdfObj = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBuffer(function (buffer) {
      let utf8 = new Uint8Array(buffer);
      let binaryArray = utf8.buffer;
      self.saveToDevice(binaryArray,"familydescription.pdf")
      });
  // this.documentViewer.viewDocument(this.pdfObj,'application/pdf',{});
  this.fileOpener.open(this.pdfObj, 'application/pdf')
  .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
  }

  downloadPdf() {
    if (this.plt.is('cordova')) {
      this.pdfObj.getBuffer((buffer) => {
        var blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        // Save the PDF to the data Directory of our App
        this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'myletter.pdf', blob, { replace: true }).then(fileEntry => {
          // Open the PDf with the correct OS tools
          this.fileOpener.open(this.file.dataDirectory + 'myletter.pdf', 'application/pdf');
        })
      });
    } else {
      // On a browser simply use download!
      this.pdfObj.download();
    }
  }

  saveToDevice(data:any,savefile:any){
    let self = this;
    self.file.writeFile(self.file.externalDataDirectory, savefile, data, {replace:false});
    // const toast = self.toastCtrl.create({
    // message: 'File saved to your device',
    // duration: 3000,
    // position: 'top'
    // });
    //toast.present();
    console.log('file saved')
    }
}
```

I am using `"pdfmake": "^0.1.54"`

Comment: Is there any log output?

Comment: no... it working in chrome.. not working in real devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i fix the bug. my `fileopener` plugin version doesn't support the ionic -3. i changed plugin version

Comment: what is the version you used? I have the same problem with Ionic 3?

Comment: "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.20.0",

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the version of your cordova file plugin. My file plugin is not writing the file into the device.  Or if you could post your package.json it would be much helpful. Thank you.

Comment: in ionic 3 you downgrade all plugin version. i used file and file opener plugin version 4.20.0

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution that works for me.
Hope it can help [Github](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/679#issuecomment-386059406)